# Can't install latest package version from npm

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, intel-edison, johnny-five

I'm trying to install https://www.npmjs.org/package/galileo-io via npm, and it keeps on installing 0.3.10 instead of 0.4.0, which is the latest version.

Here's a screenshot when I try to force it to install 0.4.0

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMCUl.png

BTW, I'm running Yocto Linux on an Intel Edison

Comment: npm install galileo-io
or
npm install johnny-five  it's installed 0.4.0

Comment: Try run: npm cache clean first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply reflashed the device with the latest system image and I can now update to 0.4.0.